# filtering files

Tags: java

I want to check the file-type of a file. I thought about magic numbers, but how to use it 
with Java.

I want only allow Textfiles and filter files like jpg etc. in my programm.
Some ideas, what can I do.

```
private String path;
private String fileText;
private String textLine;
public LoadModel(String path) {

    this.path = path;
    this.fileText = "";

    FileReader read = null;
    BufferedReader bufRead = null;

    if (path != null && new File(path).exists()
            && !(new File(path).isDirectory())) {


        try {

            read = new FileReader(path);

            bufRead = new BufferedReader(read);
            do {
                try {
                    this.textLine = bufRead.readLine();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(LoadModel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                if (this.textLine != null) {
                    this.fileText = this.fileText + this.textLine + "\n";
                }
            } while (this.textLine != null);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(LoadModel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    } else {
        HinweisDialogController.hinweisDialogOK("Die angegebene Datei existiert nicht");

    }
}
```

Comment: is there any difficulty/issue in checking by file extensions in their names (like .jpg) using `String.endsWith(".ext")`?

Comment: the problem is, you can rename a picture.jpg to picture.txt and then this approuch would not work.

Answer (score 6):

[Here](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0487.html) you can find the list of API's available for identify mime type in java with code sample.

Also in java 7 have an option

```
Files.probeContentType(path)
```

.

Comment: Note that probeContentType is not yet implemented on Mac: http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7133484

Answer (score 3):

You can try `java.nio.file.Files.probeContentType` which is designed to determine a file content type. For example this test

```
    System.out.println(Files.probeContentType(Paths.get("1.xml")));
    System.out.println(Files.probeContentType(Paths.get("1.txt")));
```

prints

```
text/xml
text/plain
```

see API for more details

Answer (score 1):

If you need your code to work on earlier versions of JDK (not JDK7) you may use `Apache Tika's` `MimeType` detector, which has `MimeType#detect()` method

More information [here](http://tika.apache.org/1.2/detection.html#The_default_Mime_Types_Detector)